# Module installation error

Tags: python, error

I have a Blender script that requires Pillow. The snippet shown below is the part that imports it. In one computer it works totally fine, in another computer it shows the following traceback:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Multi_Material_Render.py", line 106, in <module>
    install_pillow()
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Multi_Material_Render.py", line 109, in <module>

  File "\Multi_Material_Render.py", line 102, in install_pillow
    try:
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 
369, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 
3.6\\3.6\\python\\bin\\python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--target', 'C:\\Program 
Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.6\\3.6\\python\\lib\\site-packages', 'Pillow']' returned 
non-zero exit status 3221225781.
```

both computers run Win 10. The problematic one is a fresh Win install. Blender is the only app installed. It was also working fine in that computer before reinstall. Why wont it work? I tried running as administrator. I also made sure internet is available.

```
import bpy
import os
import sys
import math
import subprocess
from bpy.props import StringProperty, EnumProperty
import pkg_resources
import platform


blender_python_path = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'bin', 'python')
custom_install_path = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'lib', 'site-packages')


def ensure_pip():
    try:
        subprocess.check_call([blender_python_path, '-m', 'ensurepip'])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print("PIP is already available.")
    else:
        print("PIP has been installed.")
ensure_pip()
       
                                                                                               
def install_pillow():                                                                                                
                                                                                                                  
    subprocess.check_call([blender_python_path, "-m", "pip", "install", "--target", 
custom_install_path, "Pillow"])

  
try:
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
except ImportError:
    print("Pillow is not installed. Installing now...")
    install_pillow()
    print("Pillow has been installed.")                                                                               
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont # Import Pillow after installation
```

Comment: Hello ! I would check user rights. Make sure blender is run in admin mode and the user has write access in Blender's installation folder

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it! I noticed that the python terminal (python.exe) was not running as standalone. All I needed to do was installing Microsoft Visual C++ modules and everything was fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

It is missing `vcruntime140.dll` and maybe other DLLs that are in the `blender.crt` folder on Windows.

`3221225781` is the `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND` error.

###### env=env

You can add the `blender.crt` folder to `os.environ['PATH']` and supply `subprocess` with `env=os.environ.copy()`.

###### Environment Variables

Add `blender.crt` to `PATH` via the Windows means. [Edit the system Environment variables](https://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-PATH-Environment-Variable-on-Windows)

###### WindowsApps

The above methods may not work in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\` for the Microsoft Store version of Blender without `shell=True`.

###### Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable

Install the [`Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable`](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/vcruntime140dll-and-msvcp140dll-missing-in-windows/caf454d1-49f4-4d2b-b74a-c83fb7c38625). Which puts the DLLs inside `C:\Windows\System32\` that is in `PATH` and works for `WindowsApps`.

###### Programmatically

Although not recommended you can also use the `pip`'s API in a separate `-b --factory-startup` Blender instance and after call `importlib.invalidate_caches()`. Works for `WindowsApps`.

```py
from pip._internal import main
main(['install', '--upgrade', 'Pillow'])
```